# Saving data in database using WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, save

I have a WPF Visual Studio 2010 application with a window containing 2 buttons and a datagrid. I want to modify the values of some row from datagrid and when the  "Set"-button is pushed the datagrid should be refreshed. The done changes should be saved only when a the Save button is pressed.

The refreshing works fine, but when I push the "save"-button I receive the following error message:

`System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

My code at set button is:

```
myObjBase selected = this.dataGrid1.SelectedItem as nyObjBase;      
myObj ist = new myObj ();    
ist.field1= "";   
ist.field2 = 22;  
selected.myObj.Add(ist);
```

and for the save button I have:

```
dataSource.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error happens when the length of the data you're trying to insert into a column is to long.

You should check the max length property in your database and make sure that users can't send a longer string then is allowed.

Comment: Thanks!! This was the problem!